# Firebase: When ordering by key, the argument passed to startAt(), endAt(),or equalTo() must be a string

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Considering a ref with children whose keys are numbers (so that with `orderByKey` "Children with a key that can be parsed as a 32-bit integer come first, sorted in ascending order")

Doing:

```
ref.orderByKey().startAt(5)
```

I am getting the following error:

> When ordering by key, the argument passed to startAt(), endAt(),or equalTo() must be a string

In the documentation for `startAt` I see:

> When used in combination with orderByKey(), the value must be a string.

Can I replace this with `ref.orderByKey().startAt("5")`? Will that still run `startAt` using numerical rather than lexicographical order?

Comment: Yep. You *have* to replace it with `ref.orderByKey().startAt("5")`, as you have to pass a string. And keys are always sorted the [same way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order) - with keys that can be parsed as a 32-bit integers coming first, sorted in numerical order.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, I get no results :(

Comment: Querying using keys that can be parsed as 32-bit integers does work as described in the documentation, but, as Michael has mentioned in his answer, you are better off not relying upon that behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the firepad code I found methods to convert a number to/from a lexicographical string so they can safely be used as keys:

```
  let characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

  // numerical to a lexigaraphically ordered string
  function revisionToId(revision) {
    if (revision === 0) return 'A0';
    let str = '';
    while (revision > 0) {
      let digit = (revision % characters.length);
      str = characters[digit] + str;
      revision -= digit;
      revision /= characters.length;
    }
    let prefix = characters[str.length + 9]; // Prefix with length (starting at 'A' for length 1) to ensure the id's sort lexicographically.
    return prefix + str;
  }

  // and reverse
  function revisionFromId(revisionId) {
    // assert(revisionId.length > 0 && revisionId[0] === characters[revisionId.length + 8]);
    let revision = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < revisionId.length; i++) {
      revision *= characters.length;
      revision += characters.indexOf(revisionId[i]);
    }
    return revision;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

All Firebase keys are strings. If you are using implicit array coercion with numeric keys, you should strongly consider switching to position as a child property. So not:

```
0: {foo: 'bar'}
```

But:

```
-Kpushidgoeshere: {position: 0, foo: 'bar'}
```

Then you would do `orderByChild('position').startAt(5)` to achieve the desired result of sorting by position. Numeric key strings are inefficient and generally difficult to work with in Firebase.

Comment: does that mean all children will have the same key ?

Comment: No, if you use `ref.push()` to create them they'll each get a randomly generated key. You can also specify your own keys, but again it's inadvisable to use integers.